# sed not expanding variable

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm creating a script updater for a project, but I'm facing a weird issue in sed (using SLES 11 PL4). In the line below, bash/sed is simply not expanding the variable, no matter what I do:

```
oldvars=`sed -n '/#### Variables configurables ####/,/#### Variables configurables ####/p' ACCBackup.sh`; sed -i "/#### Variables configurables ####/,/#### Variables configurables ####/c\$oldvars" temp_ACCBackup.sh
```

Also echoing the variable works fine:

```
oldvars=`sed -n '/#### Variables configurables ####/,/#### Variables configurables ####/p' ACCBackup.sh`; echo $oldvars                                   #### Variables configurables #### para='/mnt/BackupBBDD' # DIRECTORIO DESTINO compartido=TRUE # VAMOS A MONTAR ALGUN RECURSO COMPARTIDO? 'TRUE' O 'FALSE' compartido_externo='//IP/recurso' # RECURSO EN MAQUINA EXTERNA compartido_usuario='xxxx' # USUARIO PARA EL RECURSO COMPARTIDO compartido_contrasena='yyyy' # CONTRASENA PARA EL RECURSO COMPARTIDO #### Variables configurables ####
```

I tried changing the escape '\', putting the variable inside '{}'s, but none helped... This is getting weirder as I try new options. The system simply puts ONLY the variable name and not its content.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: may be the ``\`` after `c` command is causing the issue... try using ``\\`` instead... if you create simple sample input and show output required, you might get better help... I think you should use `r` command for robustness

Comment: Can you add input and actual/desired output, and the contents of `oldvars`?

Comment: The shell correctly replaces the string `\$oldvars` with the string `$oldvars`.  If you want the value of the variable, you should not escape the `$`.

Comment: If I read this right, you're replacing the block between sentinel strings with the previous value of the variable, and putting the old values from pre-replacement into the variable. This is ~ clever ~ in the not-so-flattering way. Break it into multiple steps that will not couple failure into the backup. Add some error checking. And for goodness sake, put that redundant string in a short variable for consistent reuse. Would you like help accomplishing those things?

Comment: Hello all, thanks for the suggestions but I already tested using \\ (forgot to mention, sorry)... Basically sed do not allow anything different than /c\...

Answer (score 2):

Or, you can use the below:

```
OLDVAR=abc
NEWVAR=xyz

sed -i 's/'"$OLDVAR"'/'"$NEWVAR"'/g' filename
```

Works for me everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Add another `\` before the variable.

`\\$oldvars`

When you used single `\` the `$` is escaped and `$oldvars` became a normal string instead of variable.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer but I already tested using \\ (forgot to mention, sorry)... Basically sed do not allow anything different than /c\...

Comment: Have you found any solution?  "already tested using \\" - did this work? If not, then you may try something like `sed -i "/#### Variables configurables ####/c $oldvars" temp_ACCBackup.sh `